# Properly deploying Nginx+React+FastAPI+SQLite+Docker keeping things secure (protecting the backend etc.)

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, fastapi

after what felt like an eternity (and many talks with Copilot) I managed to deploy my little homepage in my local network.

On the frontend side, I'm doing authentication via Firebase Google SSO, but I realized that the backend is completely open (e.g. if I go on IP:80/api/emails I get the get endpoint that shows the rows in the emails table). I thought that would be avoided with Nginx and now I'm not sure what that's even for.

What am I still missing to deploy it outside of my network? I want to have it running on a raspberry pi connected to my router. For the record, the users will only be around 15 friends who I completely trust.

These are my Dockerfiles and the docker-compose. This is in part also so that people who search for this exact techstack combination find this, as I was really struggling to get it to work as a total noob.

React/frontend Dockerfile

```
# Build stage
FROM node:16.13 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

React api.js (for good measure)

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.2.32/api', // This is my local IP
});

export default api;
```

FastAPI/backend Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Define the command to run your app using uvicorn
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
}
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - './backend:/app'
      - './backend/database:/app/database'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/app'
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './frontend/build:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Comment: The two important things I'd call out for deployment are to delete the `ports:` for everything other than the `nginx` service (which would let you bypass the proxy) and to delete the `volumes:` that inject code (the code won't be locally accessible on the deployed system).  Also consider using a standalone database container like PostgreSQL (and probably backing it with a Docker named volume); this will be easier to manage than trying to keep the SQLite state inside one of your existing containers.

Comment: If I delete the ports in the docker-compose and the nginx.conf has proxy_pass http://frontend:3000 and backend:8000, how would it route correctly?

Comment: I'd say, _always_ use `name` for your containers. Since the containers are in one `docker-compose.yml` file, they are by default created in one network. Then after removing the `3000` and `8000` port mappings, `nginx` will still be able to see them. Next, set `nginx` to use `IPADDR:HOSTPORT:CONTAINERPORT` as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-1), eg. `192.168.2.32:80:80`. This should not expose the container beyond your local network.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood the question. You want to make the nginx container available publicly, but want to protect it from unauthorized access, do I get it right now? Then you need to set up the authorization checks in your code, and that goes beyond docker or nginx. When the user logs in via google sso, you might want to set a JWT token in a cookie or a storage like pinia (I'm a vue person, not a react person). Then send the token with every request and check it with your api

Comment: Connections between containers don't require `ports:`, and ignore them if they're present.  The `proxy_pass` URLs will work fine without `ports:` and without `container_name:`.